# I am unable to identify whether this is a plugin, theme feature, or a custom code (Theme: Flatsome)

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am looking at a website for inspiration but am unable to figure out whether the feature highlighted in red rectangle is a plugin or custom code. I've tried the plugin detection tool, and posted on other forums as well but to no avail. Theme in the screenshots is Flatsome. If anyone help or point me in the right direction, i'd be grateful. Thanks in advance. Website link: https://greensociety.cc/product-category/summer-blow-out-sale/
[image]

[image]